# why is my async function coming out empty

Tags: vue.js, promise, axios

```
<div class="pt-5" v-for="category in categories" :key="category.id">
    <h2 class="mb-0 px-1 mx-0 text-white bg-dark w-100">{{ category.name }}</h2>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-6" v-for="product in products(category.id)" :key="product.id">
            <product class="product-height" :product="product"></product>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to display 6 products for each category.
I can't just get it to work!

```
async products(param){
    const { data } = await axios.get('url/?query='+param)
    return data
}
```

EDITED
Ok I have two endpoints that handles categories and products data. The products data have a categories attributes ( Array of Object ) that points back to each category.

I want to re-map each category data to contain a property that point to array of products.
After re-map, each category should be:

```
{
    att1: data1,
    att2: data2,
    att..n: data..n,
    products: Array of products
}
```

I did this

```
getCategoriesWithProducts(){
    var categories = this.$store.state.products.categories
    categories.map(category => {
        return this.axios.get('products?category='+category.id).then(({data}) => {
            category['products'] = data.slice(0, 6)
            return category
         })
    })
    return categories
}
```

Now the page is loaded for the first time I got an `Array []`. But when page is refresh, The array was populated.
Now this is not my intended behaviour, I need the array filled when the page is loaded the first time.

Meanwhile, I'm using VueJS. it does not work on created nor mounted hook.

Comment: Because `v-for` does not support iterating the promise it returns

Comment: @Bergi How can one go about this?

Comment: In general, have your controller load the data, then - asynchronously! - after the data loaded render it. But you haven't shown a lot of your code, not even mentioned what framework you use, so I can't be more specific.

Comment: @bergi please check from edited

Comment: The `getCategoriesWithProducts` needs to return a promise - use `Promise.all`, and you'll need to wait for that promise at the call site

Comment: How do you await a Promise in a vue component?